# Change value of multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I need a solution to change the value of an element in a multidimensional ArrayList in Java. This is my ArrayList:
    public class Users {

```
ArrayList<ValidateUser> personer = new ArrayList<ValidateUser>();

public Users() {
  personer.add(new ValidateUser("admin", "asdf123", 0.8, "admin"));
  personer.add(new ValidateUser("jesper", "ukamm19", 2.5, "user"));
  personer.add(new ValidateUser("lars", "lol123", 1.5, "user"));
}
```

I want to change the double value (0.8) at the user "admin", for example.
This would be done from another a class.
How to do so?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This doesn't look multidimensional. Just iterate through the list to find the object. If you're going to do this a lot, consider using a map.

Comment: As @ZongZhengLi already said, locate the object within the list and change its value. That's all.

Comment: I'm very new to java, so sorry if i'm incorrect in the term of multidimensional.

Comment: not probs, just use get method of list and change value of object you get.. :)

Answer (score 1):

As I've stated in my comment, just iterate through the list to find the object. If you're going to do this a lot, consider using a map.

```
for (ValidateUser user : personer)
    if (user.getName().equals("admin"))
        user.setNumber(someNumber);
```

Comment: WOuldn't this throw a ConcurrentModificationException ?

Comment: @Adarsh Nope, we're modifying the object, not the list.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that this is not a multidimensional array, is just a list that holds elements of `ValidateUser` class object references. Second, you need to access to the element before updating it. You have several ways to accomplish this:

1. Implement the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `ValidateUser` class, then just retrieve the object from your List:

   ```
   ValidateUser adminUser = personer.get(new ValidateUser("admin", "", 0.8, ""));
   adminUser.set...
   ```

   Note: this looks ridiculous but will work (assuming your `equals` method only checks by the field that holds this `"admin"` value.
2. Navigate through the array and seek for the desired element manually, then update it:

   ```
   for (ValidateUser user : personer) {
       if ("admin".equals(user.getXxx()) {
           user.set...
           break; //don't forget this!
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use a different data structure like a `Map<String, ValidateUser>` to store your data and faster retrieval:

   ```
   Map<String, ValidateUser> personerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, ValidateUser>();
   personerMap.add("admin", new ValidateUser("admin", ...);
   //fill the map with other values...
   //if you still want a Collection<ValidateUser> personer variable
   Collection<ValidateUser> personer = personerMap.values();

   //now check for the desired element
   ValidateUser admin = personerMap.get("admin");
   if (admin != null) {
       admin.set...
   }
   ```

---

By comments, your `ValidateUser` is an immutable object, so you cannot update its fields using setters (because there aren't). So, the best approach here is to use a `ListIterator<ValidateUser>` instead (not to confuse with `Iterator`) and replace the element by your modified object. Here's an example:

```
//the new immutable ValidateUser that will replace the older one...
//set the parameters as needed
ValidateUser newAdmin = new ValidateUser("admin", ...);
ListIterator<ValidateUser> listIterator = personer.listIterator();
while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
    ValidateUser validateUser = listIterator.next();
    if ("admin".equals(validateUser.getXxx()) {
        listIterator.set(newAdmin);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Luiggi, thanks for a great answer. I'm going with option 2, but is having a problem with .set method as well.
I have a double variable called "temp", which should be replacing the content. My code goes as users.personer.set(i, temp); in my for-loop, but it gives me error. What is the problem?

Comment: Instead of use `personer.set(index, temp)`, find the `ValidateUser validateUser` object in your `personer` list, then modify this `validateUser` object (by using its set methods).

Comment: My ValidateUser does not have set-method, they all get set by the constructor in ValidateUser.

Comment: @JesperBaungårdBruunHansen you have to note that in the question then. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: yeah, my bad. Im so lost with this code, the help is very appreciated! :)

Comment: Thanks for new code, but the rest of my program is built with a normal ArrayList. Is it possible for me to convert my ValidateUser to use setters? I can't see how i should construct my arraylist objects, without setting them trough the constructor.